# How to convert this multidimensional object as mentioned below in Scala?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I would like to convert the following RDD

```
(4,List((5,List(8, 9, 4, 6))))
```

to

```
(4,5,8),(4,5,9),(4,5,4),(4,5,6)
```

I have tried it using map/flatMap but could not able to achieve it. Can someone help me with this in scala?

Comment: can you post the code which you tried and failed ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this

```
val rdd = sc.parallelize(List((4,List((5,List(8, 9, 4, 6))))))
val res = rdd.flatMap{
   case (v1, l) =>
      l.flatMap{
         case (v2, l2) => 
             l2.map(v3 => (v1, v2, v3))
      }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you need something for this specific case, or you need a solution that will have a number of nested Lists varying. If it is just for this specific case than this would maybe be the solution

```
val value: (Int, List[(Int, List[Int])]) = (4, List((5, List(8, 9, 4, 6))))

  val toList = {
    value._2.flatMap(obj => {
      obj._2.map(obj2 => {
        (value._1, obj._1, obj2)
      }
      )
    })
  }
```